# Best way to match key phrases from the list of notes

Tags: python, sql, r, sql-server

I am a SQL person and for the first time got a request to dive into analytics and not sure if I can achieve this in sql.
I have a table with columns

> Person ID, Person Name, Note ID, Note (notes is a free form text where a call representative can enter their comments) Insert User

I have been given

> List of key phrases

to be identified from the notes column. These key phrases are in a sentence format.
I have to find exact or a similar matching phrase from those notes. Also, the notes can have more than one key phrases present. The format of my final report would look something like this

[image]

Pl note: I came across couple of similar questions but it was very confusing and not exactly what I am looking for. 
Please let me know what will be the best method to achieve this. Thank you!

Comment: Full text search - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017 - is usually employed for such tasks, although you might need some post-processing to validate inexact results.

Comment: "Exact or similar matching" is not really what SQL does.  For full sentences, SQL is not the best choice, unless you have an extension to deal specifically with text.

Comment: I thought so and that's why I use tags such as python and R. but they were removed not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a full-text index on your table, something like this might work:

```
declare @phrase nvarchar(255) = 'Cat is friendly, cat like to sing'

SELECT *, @phrase AS [Phrase Present] FROM dbo.Person 
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(dbo.Person, *, @phrase) ftt ON
        ftt.[key] = Person.PersonID
ORDER BY ftt.[rank] DESC
```

returns the following

```
PersonID    PersonName  NoteID  Note                      Phrase Present
111         John Doe    1234    I have a cat.             Cat is friendly, cat like to sing
                                Her name is Meow. 
                                She is very friendly. 
                                She likes to be pampered. 
                                Her favorite food is milk. 
                                She likes to sing.
```

For more information, see the [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/freetexttable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on `FREETEXTTABLE`.